# How do I get the covariance of a time series

Tags: time-series, covariance

I have the following time series: $$y_t = \mu_t + \sigma_tx_t$$

I want to get the covariance from this time series. How would one proceed with this? I have found the following formula: $$cov(x, y) = E[(x - Ex)(y - Ey)]$$

However, I am clueless on how to implement this formula to my series.

Many thanks.

Comment: Covariance is estimated from two variables, x and y. You only have one, y. Are you searching for autocorrelation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've random processes instead of variables, in which you can calculate the covariance between samples at specific times, i.e. $\operatorname{cov}(x_{t_1},y_{t_2})$, and this is a function of $t_1,t_2$. We have a name for it, as also pointed out in the comments: [cross-covariance](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Cross-covariance). In case of [joint stationarity](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Stationary_process#/Joint_strict-sense_stationarity), this function becomes univariate and depends only on $t_1-t_2$.